# passing variable to another page for sql query

Tags: php, mysql, ibm-cloud, cleardb

I am trying to pass a variable from a page to another page so that i can display more information on the other page by getting the idea. I am not really sure what is going wrong and because I use bluemix it doesn`t display an error it just gives me the page 500 error. Here is my code:

```
<?php
     $strsql = "select id, name, problem, urgency, technology from idea WHERE status='saved'";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($strsql)) {
       // printf("<br>Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
    } else {
            //Could be many reasons, but most likely the table isn't created yet. init.php will create the table.
            echo "<b>Can't query the database, did you <a href = init.php>Create the table</a> yet?</b>";
        }

      ?>


  <?php
                        echo "<tr>\n";
                        while ($property = mysqli_fetch_field($result)) {
                                echo '<th>' .  $property->name . "</th>\n"; //the headings

                        }
                        echo "</tr>\n";

                         while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row ( $result ) ) {
                            $idea_id= $row['id'];
                            echo "<tr>\n";
                            for($i = 0; $i < mysqli_num_fields ( $result ); $i ++) {
                              echo <a href ="meerinfo.php?idea= '. $idea_id .'">  '<td>' . "$row[$i]" . '</td>'</a>;
                            }
                            echo "</tr>\n";
                        }


                        $result->close();
                        mysqli_close();
                    ?>
```

Comment: Two extra `<?php  <?php` inside your code

Comment: no that is just i mistake i made when i posted it sorry

Comment: Can you provide a `print_r($row);` from inside the while loop?

Comment: did you really need these?  $result->close();
                        mysqli_close();

Comment: Try to comment out lines. Start with the else statement and comment out the echo line. Also try and look in the server log files.

Comment: this is what is get Jan Array ( [0] => 32 [1] => lol8 [2] => lol [3] => lol [4] => lol ) 32 is the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a small bug in your code. Your `echo <a href ="...` line should be like this,

```
echo '<td><a href ="meerinfo.php?idea='. $idea_id .'">' . $row[$i] . '</a></td>';
```

Comment: The error isn`t showing up anymore Rajdeep but the row is not a link?

Comment: @user3356007 Which row? Are you talking about `$row[$i]`?

Comment: yes i want the row to send the id to the next page moreinfo but the row isn`t a link now

Comment: The row show all the information i requested on the database and it ads a new row for every new ID that is working fine but i want to make the row clickable and send the id with it so i can use the id for a new query on the other page and display all the information

Comment: it is working now it is a link but it isn`t passing any ID to the other page so there is someting from with putting the id in the variable $idea_id

Comment: @user3356007 So the `$idea_id` is not showing up in the links, right?

Comment: @user3356007 The problem is you're fetching the result row as an enumerated array, so you can't use `$row['id'];` to get the id of the row. Change `$idea_id= $row['id'];` to `$idea_id= $row[0];`. As a **sidenote**, don't mix procedural and object oriented style of `mysqli`.